# Clojure Spec: How can I spec a tuple as a function argument?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have a function in Clojure that accepts a 2-element vector as an argument:

```clj
(defn influence [[school value]])
```

I would like to write a spec for the arguments to this function using existing specs I have registered:

```clj
(s/fdef influence :args (s/cat :arg (s/cat :school ::school, :value ::value))
```

However, this does not work, the nested `s/cat` calls operate at the top level and apply the spec for `::school` to the whole argument list. There is also a function called `s/tuple`, which might suggest you can do

```clj
(s/fdef ->influence :args (s/cat :influence (s/tuple ::school ::value)))
```

But this also doesn't work. Spec appears to somehow get confused and try to conform the *spec name* to the spec:

`val: :my.ns/school fails spec: :my.ns/school at: [:args :school] predicate...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start off like so using a regular function of 2 args:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
    [clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest]
    ))

(defn name-age
  [name age]
  (format "name=%s  age=%d" name age))

(s/fdef  name-age
  :args (s/cat
          :name string?
          :age pos-int? ) )

(dotest
  (spyx (name-age "joe" 42))
  (stest/instrument `name-age)
  (throws? (spyx (name-age "jill" :24))))
```

with result

```
(name-age ["joe" 42]) => "name=joe  age=42"
```

and then rewrite it as a fn of 1 arg that is a tuple:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
    [clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest] ))

(s/def ::name string?)
(s/def ::age pos-int?)
(s/def ::na-tup (s/cat :name-arg ::name :age-arg ::age))

(defn name-age
  [na-tup]
  (s/valid? ::na-tup  na-tup)
  (let [[name age] na-tup]
    (s/valid? ::name name)
    (s/valid? ::age age)
    (format "name=%s  age=%d" name age)))

(s/fdef  name-age
  :args (s/cat
          :name ::name
          :age ::age ) )

(dotest
  (spyx (name-age ["joe" 42]))
  (stest/instrument `name-age)
  (throws? (spyx (name-age ["jill" :24]))) )
```

If desired, you can also get some help destructuring the data in the `name-age` function:

```
(s/conform ::na-tup na-tup) => 
    {:name-arg "joe", :age-arg 42}
```

---

### Live code examples

I worked through the Clojure Spec docs and made them into live units that [may be seen here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/x/spec.clj).  Will probably break them out into a separate repo at some point.